# raw_input does not get processed thru subprocess and pyqt4 threads

Tags: multithreading, subprocess, stdin, qthread

I have searched for days trying to figure this out, but while many answers are helpful, none of them seems to point out to the problem I am having.

I am developing a code in python that opens a test cell GUI, runs another python script from the chosen menu, and displays the output in the test cell's debug view which is a simple QTextEdit window.

Everything works fine until there is a raw_input in the python code that is supposed to run thru subprocess.  In other words, if there is no raw_input in the code, everything is fine. But when I try to run the python script that has raw_input, the python test cell code simply hangs in there waiting forever for the input, but the input, or message never shows.

I tried to use communicate(), tried to write to stdin, or to read the input, but I was either getting errors, or the script simply falls thru and does nothing.

The two python scripts I am trying to test are simple ping tests.  One has IP Address hardcoded inside the script, and the other has raw_input asking the user to enter the IP Address, and that is is the one that won't run, just sitting there waiting for the input that never shows in stdout.

I am using subprocess trying to achieve this.  Here is the portion of the code that is giving me problems.  This function is inside the Qthread, runs subprocess, and signals are put in place to display whatever print statement is written in the ping test code.

```
def _run_script(self):
    """
    This function starts the script.
    """
    IN()

    print "\nInside the thread, running script: ", self.currentScript
    print "Started running script thread"

    ##process = Popen(['python', '-u', self.currentScript], stdout = PIPE, stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)

    ##process = Popen(['python', '-u', self.currentScript], stdout = PIPE, stdin = open(os.devnull), stderr = PIPE)

    process = Popen(['python', '-u', self.currentScript], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)

    while process.poll() is None:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        line = line.strip()
        print line
        self.emit(SIGNAL("update_debug_view(QString)"), line)


    ##process = Popen(['python', '-u', self.currentScript], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)

    ##for xline in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    ##    line = xline.rstrip()
    ##    print line
    ##    self.emit(SIGNAL("update_debug_view(QString)"), line)

    print "script run finished..."

    errors = process.stderr.readline()
    print "Errors: ", errors

    self.emit(SIGNAL("check_for_errors(QString)"), errors)

    OUT()
```

I can put the entire code here, but there are multiple files, some close to 1000 lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include some of the errors you were seeing at runtime.

Comment: That's just it:  I am not seeing any errors.  And nothing indicates there are any runtime errors.  The application just sits there waiting and waiting forever.  I think because process.poll() is None and never finishes, which kind of makes sense.  It is the same as if you would run only ping test file, and the python sits at the input waiting.  Only in this case this input is never displayed in the QTextEdit box because I can't get the stdin to show up.

Comment: That's just it:  I am not seeing any errors.  And nothing indicates there are any runtime errors.  The application just sits there waiting and waiting forever.  I think because process.poll() is None and never finishes, which kind of makes sense.  It is the same as if you would run only ping test file, and the python sits at the input waiting.  Only in this case this input is never displayed in the QTextEdit box because I can't get the stdin to show up.

Comment: So I guess my main question is twofold:  If you are using QThread to run one python script from within another, and using subprocess, how do you capture stdin and have it displayed in standard output.  And 2) How do you write some input into a QTextEdit, capture it from within main python script, and pass it over to another python script as an entry to raw_input.  Sorry if I am not clear on my question, the whole concept is kind of complicated, and maybe I am not making it clear enough.